# Python3 TypeError: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, here is my code..
But I get error, attached... Please help me..

```
students = []

def add_student(name, student_id):
    student = {"name": name, "student_id": student_id}
    students.append(student)

name = input("Enter student name: ")
student_id = input("Enter student ID: ")

def save_file(student):
    try:
        f = open("students.txt", "a")
        f.write(student + "\n")
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Could not save file")

add_student(name, student_id)
save_file(name, student_id)
```

Comment: can you please show the stacktrace? what is your expected behaviour? please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would want both name and student_id to be stored in students.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `save_file` method takes a variable called `student` but you pass in `name` and `student_id`. So, your method expects one argument but got two. Ergo your error.

You can modify the method to take both the name and ID by adding another argument, similar to what you did with `add_student`. I would also advise that you look at the stack trace and try to understand what's going on before you ask questions. You'll learn more that way and you may come to understand your problem without seeking help.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

The function `save_file()` is allowed to get only one argument `student`, but you are passing two arguments `name, student_id` to the function. That's the error!

Change `def save_file(student)` as `def save_file(student, student_id):` to fix the error.

Hope this helps! Cheers!